# How to add Item in Folder present in the list using REST API in SharePoint?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, directory

The below code successfully adds items in the list, but I want to add item in the folder which is present in the list using REST API, list name is "Designation" and folder name is "Folder1". What changes should I make to insert item in folder?

```
$.ajax({
          url:"https://brillio446.sharepoint.com/teams/Social2016/work/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Designation')/items", 
          method:"POST",
          dataType:"json",

          data: JSON.stringify({
                                               '__metadata': {'type': 'SP.Data.DesignationListItem' },
                                               'Title': 'D1',

                                            }),

          headers: {
                           "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                           "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                           "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),

                        },
          success: function(data){
                         alert("Item added successfully!");
                        },
          error: function(err){
                            alert("Error while adding item: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                        }
});
```

I also find that folder path should be there so I tried this code...
But I got error that 'Path' does no exist in `SP.Data.DesigantionListItem`

```
data: JSON.stringify({
   '__metadata': {'type': 'SP.Data.DesignationListItem' },
   'Title': 'D1',
   'Path': '/ServerRelativeUrl of folder',
}),
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but search led me here, so adding answer for others.
As Vadim mentioned, `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListTitle')/items` method does not support adding items to folder.

Instead, you should use `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListTitle')/AddValidateUpdateItemUsingPath` method.

Just make sure, you use string values instead of numbers or dates or similar, because it works same as you enter form - parse, validate and save values.

**MSDN Reference**: [Create list item in a folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#create-list-item-in-a-folder)

### Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"https://brillio446.sharepoint.com/teams/Social2016/work/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Designation')/AddValidateUpdateItemUsingPath", 
    method:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data: JSON.stringify({{
        "listItemCreateInfo": {
            "FolderPath":  { "DecodedUrl": "/ServerRelativeUrl of folder" },
            "UnderlyingObjectType": 0
        },
        "formValues": [
            {
                "FieldName": "Title",
                "FieldValue": "D1"
            }
        ],
        "bNewDocumentUpdate": false
    }),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert("Item added successfully!");
    },
    error: function(err){
        alert("Error while adding item: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is not supported to specify folder url while creating list item but you could consider the following approach:

- create a `ListItem` resource
- get *associated* `File` resource and move it into folder

**Example**

```
function executeJson(options) 
{
    var headers = options.headers || {};
    var method = options.method || "GET";
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(options.method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: options.url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if("payload" in options) {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(options.payload);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}



function createListItem(listTitle,properties,folderUrl){
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items";
    return executeJson({
        "url" :url,
        "method": 'POST',
        "payload": properties})
        .then(function(result){
             var url = result.d.__metadata.uri + "?$select=FileDirRef,FileRef";
             return executeJson({url : url});
        })
        .then(function(result){
             var fileUrl = result.d.FileRef;
             var fileDirRef = result.d.FileDirRef;
             var moveFileUrl = fileUrl.replace(fileDirRef,folderUrl);
             var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('" + fileUrl + "')/moveto(newurl='" + moveFileUrl + "',flags=1)";
             console.log(url);
             return executeJson({
                  "url" :url,
                  "method": 'POST',
                  });
        });
}
```

Usage

```
var listTitle = "Requests";  //list title
var targetFolderUrl = "/Lists/Requests/Archive";  //folder server relative url
var itemProperties = {
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.RequestsListItem" },
    "Title": 'Request 123'
};


createListItem(listTitle,itemProperties,targetFolderUrl)
.done(function(item)
{
    console.log('List item has been created');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/a0de978dceb2cc671e0f0f2a3459c410)

Comment: Above code is not working. It's giving error as 'Value does not fall within the expected range'